# I want to display data in textfield. when search data have

Tags: laravel

I want to display data in textfield . Not all data. When search by name and it have data then went to display data in textfield. And search form and want to display form is same form.

```
   <form action="postAuth" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="productname"         placeholder="Search Product"> <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="search">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
     </button>
 </span>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="ProductName" >Product Name :</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProductName">
    </div>

  </form>
```

route

```
    Route::post("postAuth", ['as' => 'search' , 'uses'=> 'ProductController@postAuth']);
```

That's my controller

```
    public function postAuth(Request $request)
{
  //check submit
  $update = $request->get('update',false);
  if($update){
    return $this->update($request);
  }
  $productname = $request->input('productname');
  $product = DB::table('products')
  ->where('product_name','LIKE','%'.$productname.'%')
  ->get();
  if($product->count() > 0)
    return redirect()->to('/update')->withDetails($product)->withQuery($productname);
  else
    $request->session()->flash('alert-danger','No Data Found!');
    return redirect()->to('/update');
}
```

can anyone help me please

Comment: use ajax and if find data then js put it in dom

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your inputs and outputs, so we know exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: do you guys can show me a simple example for search and display in one form

Comment: @roelofs i'm trying to post data into textfield . Get data and Post data is in one form.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you exactly want : Just for example

```
 <div class="form-group">
   {{Form::label('name', trans('admin.venue.fields.name'),['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}
       <div class="col-md-6">
         {{Form::text('name',old('name', isset($venue) ? $venue->name : ''),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
      </div> 
 </div>
```

Model function example :

```
public function save(Request $request) {
    try {
        $this->validate($request, Venue::rules(),  Venue::messages());
        $venue = Venue::saveOrUpdate($request);
        if($venue !== false) {
            if($request->get('continue', false)) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.venue.edit', ['id' => $venue->id])->with('success', trans('admin.venue.save_success'));
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('admin.venue.index')->with('success', trans('admin.venue.save_success'));
            }
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to save venue")->withInput();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return back()->with('error', "Unable to save venue")->withInput();
    }
}
```

Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

use `session()` in the value field of ProductName `input` tag and with some logic, for example

view file:

```
@if(session()->has('data'))
    @if(count(session('data')))
        @foreach(session('data') as $data)
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProductName" value="{{ $data->prodcut_name }}">
        @endforeach
    @else
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProductName" value="No Data Available">
    @endif
@else
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ProductName">
@endif
```

and in Controller:

```
public function postAuth(Request $request) {
    $productname = $request->input(productname);
    $product_search = Products::where('product_name', $productname)->get();
    if($product_search) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('data', $product_search);
    }
}
```